# Rewrite URL not working in .htaccess drupal 8

Tags: .htaccess, drupal, drupal-8

I have successfully implemented pagination in a drupal 8 view block.
Now it generates the following URL for me :

`http://tommiecrawford.local/node?page=1`

But i don't want this.

I want to have the following urls for my pagination links.

`http://tommiecrawford.local/blog/page/1`

`http://tommiecrawford.local/blog/page/2`

`http://tommiecrawford.local/blog/page/3`

etc..

I already tried this with htaccess but it's not working with the following config :

`RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} page=$`

`RewriteRule . http://tommiecrawford.local/blog/page/$1 [R=301,L]`

Is there a module or a fix for this?

Thanks.

Comment: Does your server allows you to override their configuration in an htaccess? Else, your htaccess will not even be considered

Comment: Yes the server allows to override configuration Yann

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+node\?page=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /blog/page/%1? [R=302,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^blog/page/(.+?)/?$ /node?page=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```